# 2-Dim square lattice band structure with spin orbit interaction

Tags: wavefunction, group-theory, crystals

I'd like to derive the band structure of a 2D square lattice from the $\Gamma$ to the X point via the $\Delta$ direction with spin orbit coupling turned on! I already got the bandstructure without.
So now I am not shure what to do. I have the character tables of the double groups of $C_4v$,$C_2v$ and $C_1h$. Do I just again caluculate all symmetry adjusted wave functions? 
Note: Only the energy levels up to E = 2 are relevant.

Comment: I did some work with band structure for my MS, but that was some time ago and I've since twice changed fields. That said, I can't imagine the work *not* being a full recalculation, so it's not clear to me what the actual question is here.